# Is there any advantage to Ajax get data type XML over Json?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

Is there any advantage to using Ajax to get data formatted as XML over Json format?
Should we now call it Ajaj?

Comment: Are you asking if JSON gives an advantage over XML?

Comment: @Jonathan M - the other way, if XML has any advantage I am not aware of (like quick search in the returned data etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no advantage to using XML over Json at all. Equivalent data will have a smaller footprint (memory, amount of data) than XML, hence its popularity.

`AJAX` is still used when `Json` stands for the `X` ;)

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29):

> Despite the name, the use of XML is not needed (JSON is often used instead), and the requests need not be asynchronous.[

Comment: @George - Thank you for your constructive contribution.

Comment: and also @Oded: there is no need for `AJAJ` as the first J, ie, `JavaScript` covers `JSON` which is infact `JavaScript Object Notation`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could save a little bandwidth losing the markup